# Yii2: Jquery selecting id of a table cell not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using Yii2 and using this jquery code to access the value of a cell(td) column. I have set the id of the column say 'room_name'

I am using this code which works fine on a form, but in grid-view(table) I am getting a blank alert.

```
<?php      
$script = <<<EOD
alert ($('#room_name').val());

EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);        
?>
```

Do I need to do it differently for tables, as the id is getting repeated over multiple rows.

Thanks for a suggestion.

Comment: IDs should be unique. Add class instead and use the class.

Comment: Hi @anpsmn - I have tried that variation using class as well, still I am getting a blank alert.

Comment: Looking at the code it is difficult to guess. You could try alerting just the element first then the value.

Comment: Thanks: alerting just the element I am getting [object Object]. Does that make sense.

Comment: Ok you should use .text() than .val()

Comment: Hi anpsmn - do you mean like this - `alert ($('#room_name').text().val());` - But then I am not getting any alert.

Comment: No just `$('#room_name').text()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68090/discussion-between-joshi-and-anpsmn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it from @anpsmn. Adding for record for help to others.

```
$('td.room_name').each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
})
```